# Can I use PCL library in standard .Net application?

Tags: c#, uwp, portable-class-library

I have PCL Library and I want to add it to standard (.net 4.6) C# console application. Everything is fine as long as I don't use any PCL specific classes inside the library. And if I do, I get an error "unsupported PCL profile". This error is not googlable. But the same library works fine in UWP application. I am searching for a solution or official explanation why I can't use PCL in non UWP application.

Comment: Which PCL profile are you targeting with your PCL library?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I target Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. I added .Net Framework 4.5.1 to targeted frameworks as pointed by Alexej Sommer but it seems to render most of my namespaces incompatible (see comment below Alexej's answer).

Comment: Those namespaces that you list below are *not* available in .NET. Therefore they will also not show up if you create a PCL library including .NET. For a namespace, type or method to be included in a PCL profile, it must be available on **all** the platforms that the PCL profile is targeting.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I missed that concept that PCL is just a restriction mechanism. Seems like I will have to rewrite library to be compatible with .NET framework or I will have to make Windows 8 or UWP application, not .NET framework one. What a mess. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. 
Just add .NET 4.6 to selected platforms:

[image]

It's appears at time when you create PCL.
More information here: 
[Cross-Platform Development with the Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or you can change platforms in existing PCL. Just go to properties page and you will see:

[image]

Here is a good blog post about how to call UWP API from desktop App:
[How to call UWP APIs from a desktop VB/C# app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/10/23/how-to-call-uwp-apis-from-a-desktop-vbc-app/)

Comment: Alexej, thank you, I think that it is correct. I targeted Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. As you pointed, I added .Net Framework 4.5.1 but now my library fails build - most namespaces can't be found, including 
`Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm,Windows.Devices.Enumeration, Windows.Networking,Windows.Networking.Proximity, Windows.Networking.Sockets, Windows.Storage.Streams, Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources, Windows.Devices.Geolocation` (everything in `Windows` namespace). Am I missing something? Or I can't use those in .Net Framework 4.5.2? If I need geolocation, I have to use UWP?

Comment: You can use [System.Device.Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location(v=vs.110).aspx) in your .NET app, but in this case you should to rewrite all the code.
Windows namespace is missing in .NET. I think that might be a way to reference it, but it is not recommended (I have seeing article about how to reference winrt from .NET) Ahh, here it is [Using Windows 8 WinRT APIs in .NET Desktop Applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications/)

Comment: Yup, I've already seen this in [another source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps). Looks like a dirty hack and didn't work for me. Thanks for help anyway! Seems like 80% of code will have to be rewrited. Fortunately, I already made this earlier when I tried to make this PCL COM compatible (which resulted in rewriting it to .NET 4.5).

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. PCL is basically intersection of available API's across different platforms. The disadvantage is that the more target platforms you choose the smaller is the intersection:
[image]

Another disadvantage of PCL is that it generates separate assembly for each platform.

That's why Microsoft comes with .NET Standard - a replacement of PCL that uses different approach.

Think about .NET Standard as an interface, that defines set of API's. Then the platforms like .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android will implement the .NET Standard.

```
interface NetStandard1_0 {
}

interface NetStandard1_1 : NetStandard1_0{
}

interface NetStandard1_2 : NetStandard1_1{
}

net46: NetStandard1_6 {
}

dnxcode46: NetStandard1_6 {
}
```

As a result, you won't target specific platforms, but a version of .NET Standard instead. When your library targets .NET Standard, it can be used in any platform that implements the .NET Standards. Another advantage is you wont need separate assemblies for different platforms anymore. There will be single assembly that runs just everywhere.

However, I recommend you to wait until April 2017 when .NET Standrard 2.0 should be released. Microsoft promised that all platforms (.NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android) will support this version of .NET Standard and it will have official support in Visual Studio. Also, Visual Studio projects using project.json will be converted to .csproj, so all Visual Studio projects will use the same format and it will solve a lot of compatibility issues. Cleanning of the mess that appeared in .NET last years was absolutelly necessary

Comment: Thank you for information about .Net Standard, I just wondered what is was. It really seems like a good solution for the future of this project.